# want to put @renderbody() into a partial view source by _layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Creating an MVC 3 Razor project. have a very involved UI design. I wanted to put @renderbody() into a partial view source by _layout. The compiler won't let me. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No. You can use `@RenderBody` only in layouts.

Comment: thats what i was afraid of. thanks.

Comment: Can you add little more detail of what you are trying to achieve through partial views?

Comment: ideally i want to move a big block of html (a table within a div) in a partial view. I want this markup to wrap the @renderbody(). If I can't put the @renderbody() in a partial, then the markup must be left in _layout or split between 2 partials which is messy and confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of partial view you can go for master/sub layouts.

**MasterLayout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

// html code above render body
@RenderBody()
// html code below render body
```

Your sublayout(`Layout.cshtml`) contains the code that should be in the partial view.

Comment: I didn't have the ability to vote up when this was answered. belated thanks.